# How to get column bool values by using != and judge np.nan values are FALSE?

Tags: pandas

Input

```
22465    2.0
23759    NaN
27151    NaN
23560    2.0
266      6.0
29280    7.0
37385    NaN
8408     NaN
35949    4.0
29004    NaN
```

output and trying:

```
s!=6

index
22465     True
23759     True
27151     True
23560     True
266      False
29280     True
37385     True
8408      True
35949     True
29004     True
```

expected

```
index
22465     True
23759     FALSE
27151     FALSE
23560     True
266       FALSE
29280     True
37385     FALSE
8408      FALSE
35949     True
29004     FALSE
```

I don't know how to use `is.null()` or other selecting np.nan method to let np.nan become FALSE while judging 6.0 is FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine it with `notnull`

```
(s != 6) & (s.notnull())

22465     True
23759    False
27151    False
23560     True
266      False
29280     True
37385    False
8408     False
35949     True
29004    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Updated post. .